# Ошибка преобразования константной строки в char* [-Wwrite-strings]

Tags: c++, строки, указатели, const

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class str
{
    char* arr = nullptr;
    int size = 0;
  public:
    str(char* p);
    ~str();
    void merge(const str& s);
    int find_(const str& s);
    void print();
};
str::str(char* p)
{
    size = strlen(p);
    arr = new char[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        arr[i] = p[i];
}
str::~str()
{
    delete[] arr;
    size = 0;
}
void str::print()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        cout << arr[i];
}
void str::merge(const str& s)
{
    int temp(size + s.size), counter(0);
    char* p = new char[temp];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        p[counter++] = arr[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < s.size; ++i)
        p[counter++] = s.arr[i];

    delete [] arr;
    arr = p;
    size = temp;
}
int str::find_(const str& s)  // сюда КМП бахни или хеши, сразу пятерку поставят. А мне лень што-та :)
{
    int counter(0);
    if (size < s.size)
        return -1;
    if (size == s.size)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            if (arr[i] != s.arr[i])
                return -1;
        return 0;
    }

    bool founded(false);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        counter = i;
        founded = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < s.size; ++j)
        {
            if (i == size)
                return -1;
            if (arr[i++] != s.arr[j])
            {
                founded = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        i = counter;
        if (!founded)return i;
    }

    return -1;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    str temp("Ali");
    temp.merge("ce");
    temp.print();
    cout << '\n';
    cout << temp.find_("ic") << " " << temp.find_("ce") << " " <<
         temp.find_("Ali") << " " << temp.find_("ced");
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

В следующих строках есть ошибка:

> ```
> warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
> ```

```
str temp("Ali");
temp.merge("ce");
cout << temp.find_("ic") << " " << temp.find_("ce") << " " << temp.find_("Ali") << " " << temp.find_("ced");
```

Поможете исправить ошибку???

Comment: В классе  определите  еще конструктор коопирования и оператор присваивания

Comment: Отличный комментарий у метода `find_`

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте конструктор от константной строки:

```
str::str(const char *p){
    size = strlen(p);
    arr = new char[size];
    for(int i = 0;i<size;++i)arr[i] = p[i];
}
```

Ваш конструктор сейчас фактически говорит - я буду менять переданную мне строку! но менять ваше `"Ali"` нельзя - это все-таки литерал, который изменению не подлежит...

P.S. На наличие ошибок в логике программы не смотрел.

Comment: да, ошибки в логике программы конечно есть...

Answer (score 0):

К дополнению на верный ответ от  `Harry`, у вас много логических ошибок и попытка написать код, который уже написан, и остается лишь вызывать эти функции стандартной библиотеки.  Так что я предложу такой вариант:

```
class str
{
    char* arr = nullptr;
    int size = 0;
public:
    str(const char* p);
    str(const str& s);             //нужно определять тоже
    str& operator =(const str& s); //нужно определять тоже
    ~str() { delete []arr; }
    void merge(const str&);
    int find_(const str&) const;
    void print() const;
};
str::str(const char *p) : size(strlen(p))
{
    arr = new char[size + 1];  //везде на символ больше для символа конца строки
    strcpy(arr, p);
}
str::str(const str& s)
{
    arr = new char[s.size + 1];
    strcpy(arr, s.arr);
    size = s.size;
}
str& str::operator =(const str& s)
{
    if (this != &s) {
        if (size < s.size) {
            delete []arr;
            arr = new char[s.size + 1];
        }
        strcpy(arr, s.arr);
    }
    return *this;
}
void str::merge(const str& s)
{
    size += s.size;
    char* p = new char[size + 1];
    strcpy(p, arr);  // сначала копируем `arr`
    strcat(p, s.arr); // слияние со строкой аргумента
    delete []arr;
    arr = p;
}
int str::find_(const str& s) const
{
    char* p = strstr(arr, s.arr); // возвращает ноль, если строка не найдена
    if (p)
        return p - arr;
    return -1;
}
void str::print() const
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        cout << arr[i] << ' ';
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо AR Hovsepyan за то что Вы отделини внимание и времени.
Но к сажелению, после компиляции в вашем коде тоже есть некоторые баги...

Comment: Не вижу там багов, у меня все прекрасно работает. Попробуйте подключать заголовочный файл  #include <stdlib.h>.   А по поводу времени... Особо не много времени понадобилось. Я пишу тогда, когда оно у меня есть, тем более, что  наверное вы первый армянин, которому я здесь отвечал, повлияло на мое решение написать...

Comment: Да, я у вас скопировал  все и  внес свои изменения, поэтому где то  мог упустить что то. Например прямая  инициализация закрытых данных  char* arr = nullptr;
    int size = 0;     абсолютно лишняя затея